# Invoking a methods

Tags: java

I am a newbie to Java and started to read Think Java and stuck on some exercises. Would you mind helping me out? Thanks a lot

> Fermat’s Last Theorem says that there are no integers a, b, and c such
>   that
>
> ```
> a^n + b^n = c^n
> ```
>
> except in the case when n=2. Write a method named `checkFermat(int a, int b, int c, int n)` that
>   takes four integers as parameters—a, b, c and n—and that checks to see
>   if Fermat’s theorem holds. If n is greater than 2 and it turns out to
>   be true that an + bn = cn, the program should print “Holy smokes,
>   Fermat was wrong!” Otherwise the program should print “No, that
>   doesn’t work.”
>
> You should assume that there is a method named `raiseToPow(int x, int pow`) that takes
>   two integers as arguments and that raises the first argument to the
>   power of the second. For example:
>
> ```
> int x = raiseToPow(2, 3);
> ```
>
> would assign the value 8 to x, because 2^3 = 8.
>
> ```
> public class Buzz {}
> ```

but i don't know how to surrender the values from checkFermat to the other method I have to invoke raiseToPow and how to write the method raiseToPow to work.

Answer (score 0):

If the raiseToPow method is assuming you can't use the `Math.pow()` method in Java, a way to write you're own would be:

```
public int raiseToPow(int base, int powerTo){
    if(power == 0){ 
        return 1;
    } else{
        int result = x;
        for(int i = 1; i <= powerTo; i++) {
            result = result * x;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Or if you prefer, here is a recursive method for it:

```
public int raiseToPow(int base, int powerTo){
    if(power == 0){ 
        return 1;
    }
    return base * pow(base, --power);
}
```

To check Fermat's theorem, you can then use this for an example, changing the values of the numbers if you would like:

```
public void checkFermat(int a, int b, int c, int n){
    int x = raiseToPow(a, n);
    int y = raiseToPow(b, n);
    int z = raiseToPow(c, n)
    if(x + y == z && n> 2){
        System.out.println("Holy smokes, Fermat was wrong!");
    } else{
        System.out.println("No, that doesn’t work.");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Niall but this isn't exactly what i had in mind. There should be a method checkFermat where you state the 4 integers - a, b, c and n and there should be another method that is named raisedToPow which raises a to n(a^n) and for b and c. I know how to invoke the checkFermat and assign values to it but i don't know how to write another method named raiseToPow which does the raising with the assigned values to the checkFermat method.

Comment: The answer I have has the `raiseToPow()` method and also shows how to use it in the `checkFermat()` method. Sorry I'm just a bit confused as to what you're asking in your comment since I think the code I have does what you're looking for.

Comment: It does the job :) I just wanted a different approach as i've already knew to it but thanks for confirming. It is good to have some explanation and checking.